# Angular interceptor queue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, queue, interceptor

I want to create a queue mechanism in Angular. After collecting the data in an array, I want to throw the requests in order and throw the next one when successful.

The code that I did but did not work is below

```js
private requestQueue: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];
  isQueueActive: boolean = false;
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
 
      this.requestQueue.push(request);
      if (!this.isQueueActive) {
        this.isQueueActive = true;
        return this.processQueue(next);
 }
      return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>();
    } 


  private processQueue(next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const request = this.requestQueue.shift(); 

    if (request) {
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap((data: any) => {
          this.processQueue(next);
        }),
      ); 
    } else {
      this.isQueueActive = false;
      return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>(); 
    }
  }
```

my code in this way, I am open to other suggestions, npm package etc. I would be very happy if you help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason you're struggling here is because you're trying to mix an imperative and a reactive approach. It's usually a better idea to stick to one only. When it gets to managing complex async operations, sticking to reactive programming is probably your best bet.

Here's how I'd approach it:

```js
@Injectable()
export class QueueRequestsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private intercepted$$ = new Subject<Intercepted>();

  private queue$ = this.intercepted$$.pipe(
    concatMap(({ request, next }) =>
      next.handle(request).pipe(
        materialize(),
        map((materializedResponse) => ({
          request,
          materializedResponse,
        }))
      )
    ),
    share()
  );

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return merge(
      this.queue$.pipe(
        filter((res) => res.request === request),
        first(),
        map(({ materializedResponse }) => materializedResponse),
        dematerialize()
      ),
      defer(() => {
        this.intercepted$$.next({ request, next });
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

First of all, I create a subject where we'll push our requests in queue.

Then we create the queue and use `concatMap` to make sure that the requests happen sequentially, in order.

If one request fails (if an HTTP call returns an error), we want to make sure that we don't make the entire queue error, or the queue would be lost/stopped, we use `materialize`. Whether it's a success or a throw, it'll wrap the observable result into an object. Meaning it'll never throw anymore. Then, we `map` to keep both the request as we'll want to filter on it later on and the materialized response. Finally for that block, we `share` otherwise each request would create a new subscription to the queue and nothing would be queued up.

Now, in the `intercept` block, we'll come back to the `merge` and `defer`, let's look at our queue first. We want to listen to the queue and filter for the current request only. Which we can do as using the `map` we discussed above, we returned the exact request so we can compare that directly. With the filter done, the first thing to make sure of is to avoid a potential memory leak by keeping the observable open! Because the queue will remain open, so we use `first`. Now, if the original HTTP call failed, we still want our app to receive the original behavior for that HTTP call and not the wrapped object (that we got because of `materialize` to not kill the queue). Therefore we call `dematerialize` which does the exact opposite and will throw for the current request if there was an error (but our queue will still be alive for other requests!).

Now let's get back to the merge. We could have had the following code:

```js
this.intercepted$$.next({ request, next });

return this.queue$.pipe(
  filter((res) => res.request === request),
  map(({ materializedResponse }) => materializedResponse),
  dematerialize()
);
```

It'd work in most cases... But if the request is resolved straight away (unlikely... but could happen for example in a test if you mock the http response using `of` which would be synchronously handled) OR if the HTTP call fails straight away, which I assume could happen for example when you're not connected to any network and you get an error 0, I suspect this may not even be asynchronous and therefore would be missed as we start listening to the queue too late. To make sure we cover 100% of the cases and not 99%, I've used a `merge` to make sure we start listening to the queue first, and then subscribe to the `defer` which triggers the side effect of putting the current request in the queue.

I've made a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2nfwfl?file=src%2Fqueue-requests.interceptor.ts) where I created a second interceptor to mock the responses of HTTP calls.

I've applied a 3s delay on each request and here's the output:

All at the same time we first get:

```
Putting request http://mocked-request-anyway/0 in queue
Putting request http://mocked-request-anyway/1 in queue
```

+3s:

```
Received response for request http://mocked-request-anyway/0
{count: 1}
```

+3s:

```
Received response for request http://mocked-request-anyway/1
{count: 2}
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, my problem has been solved and thank you very much for enlightening me. I am also very happy that you offer a live demo, thank you very much again.

Comment: Glad it's working :)